# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

These are the create statement for the two tables that i am facing the issue with:
First Table:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `hrm__companyteam` (
 `id_team` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_department` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `team_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `notes` mediumtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_team`),
 KEY `id_company` (`id_department`),
 CONSTRAINT `hrm__companyTeam_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_department`) REFERENCES `hrm__companydepartment` (`id_department`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `hrm__companyteam_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_department`) REFERENCES `hrm__companydepartment` (`id_department`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Second Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `hrm__companyjobtitle` (
 `id_job_title` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_team` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `job_title_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `notes` mediumtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_job_title`),
 KEY `id_division` (`id_team`),
 CONSTRAINT `hrm__companyJobTitle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_team`) REFERENCES `hrm__companyteam` (`id_team`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `hrm__companyjobtitle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_team`) REFERENCES `hrm__companyteam` (`id_team`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When i try to execute the following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO `hr_db`.`hrm__companyjobtitle` (

`id_job_title` ,
`id_team` ,
`job_title_name` ,
`notes`
)
VALUES (
'1',  '1',  'IT',  ''
)
```

I get this error:

## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hr_db`.`hrm__companyjobtitle`, CONSTRAINT `hrm__companyJobTitle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_team`) REFERENCES `hrm__companyteam` (`id_team`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Please help... What am i doing wrong. Also please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: the error says it right there , you need to insert data first in  hrm__companyteam , and can then only insert data in hrm__companytitle as the constraint specifies that hrm__companytitle.id_team must have a matching  value in hrm__companyteam.id_team

Comment: The Data is in there in the hrm_company team table already. I added 2 rows earlier. But still the same result

Comment: show your table data please

Comment: INSERT INTO `hrm__companyteam` (`id_team`, `id_department`, `team_name`, `notes`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Sales', ''),
(2, 2, 'Team no 1', '');

Comment: THis is the data i inserted which is in the table now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used these statements :

```
CREATE TABLE `hrm__companyteam` (
    `id_team` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_department` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `team_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `notes` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_team`),
    INDEX `id_company` (`id_department`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;


CREATE TABLE `hrm__companyjobtitle` (
    `id_job_title` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_team` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `job_title_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `notes` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_job_title`),
    INDEX `id_division` (`id_team`),
    CONSTRAINT `hrm__companyJobTitle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_team`) REFERENCES `hrm__companyteam` (`id_team`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;


INSERT INTO hrm__companyteam (id_team, id_department, team_name, notes) VALUES (1, 1, 'Sales', ''), (2, 2, 'Team no 1', '');

INSERT INTO hrm__companyjobtitle (id_job_title , id_team , job_title_name , notes ) VALUES ( '1', '1', 'IT', '' );
```

AND ALL of them ran successfully without any error

Comment: I am still getting the error. Can it be because of relation with another table like the table team has relation wit another table?

Comment: yes it could be that your companydepartment table data does not has the data

Comment: Data is there in all the related tables but stil this error shows up

Comment: Yeah all of it is realted should i send you the whole database query so you can check?

Comment: send please I will check , send all 3 table create code , all 3 table insert code

Comment: Any luck with the above @satya?

Comment: Yes I think I found the error. Your SQL Script had same constraint being added twice on the same column, hence the error. I am uploading the correct SQL script, running on my system,  on dropbox and pasting the link in a short while. Here goes the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/52k6kmellt5rxgl/hr_db_2.sql

Comment: i'm getting this error while importing big database. is there any way to import without error?